# How to configure Database for WordPress to automatically Detect Local and Live Server?

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress, config

I'm working on a WordPress project where there is a local development environment and a remote server environment.

I want to set up the wp-config to detect wither it is local or remote.

If it is local, then one database connection is defined, if it is remote then another database connection is defined.

I've seen this achieved with a config created to be used with Google App Engine.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) && strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'],'Google App Engine') !== false) {
    /** Live environment Cloud SQL login and SITE_URL info */
    define('DB_HOST', ':/cloudsql/pro-tracker-639:wordpress');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
} else {
    /** Local environment MySQL login info */
    define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
```

How would I do this for a regular dedicated hosting environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way might be to switch on HTTP_HOST and define parameters specific to each domain accordingly.

```
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'environment.dev' :
        define('DB_NAME', 'dev_db');
        define('DB_USER', 'dev_user');
        define('DB_PASSWORD', 'dev_password');
        define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
        define('WP_DEBUG', true );
        define('WP_CACHE', false);
        break;

    default : // assuming this is the live environment
        define('DB_NAME', 'live_db');
        define('DB_USER', 'live_user');
        define('DB_PASSWORD', 'live_password');
        define('DB_HOST', 'db.example.com');
        define('WP_DEBUG', false);
        define('WP_CACHE', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i always create 3 config files:

- wp-local-config.dist.php
- wp-live-config.dist.php
- wp-test-config.dist.php

than in my main wp-config file i do something like that:

```
if ( file_exists( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-local-config.php' ) ) {
    // Local
    include( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-local-config.php' );
} elseif ( file_exists( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-test-config.php' ) ) {
    // Test
    include( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-test-config.php' );
} else {
    // Live
    include( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-live-config.php' );
}
```

in those files i define what ever is right for the environment:

```
// ===================================================
// DB config
// ===================================================

define( 'DB_NAME', '' );
define( 'DB_USER', '' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '' );
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );


// ===================================================
// Various
// ===================================================

define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
define( 'SAVEQUERIES', true );
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );


// ===================================================
// Cache
// ===================================================

define( 'WP_CACHE', false );
```

in wp-live-config.php WP_DEBUG should be always set to false

on each server remove the .dist from the right file